# Idiomatic translation of "把英语捡起来" in spoken English?

Tags: idiomatic-language, spoken-english, translation

A friend informed me that they haven't been practicing English for a while and would like to "pick up" their English learning journey again. In Chinese, they say "我最近好久没学英语了，得把英语捡起来".

In this context, ["捡起来"](https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s?__biz=MzA3NzMzNjgwNQ==&mid=404068683&idx=1&sn=639633a2694a3914445f9c8b458037ca&chksm=02b2a0c135c529d7de8c6e01f84cf0ccb6dd22f4afab8a875bdbc8d35cd20336cf21941111fe&scene=27) conveys the meaning of "resume doing something" which may not be idiomatic. More specifically, they abandoned using or learning English unconsciously for a long time and wanted to deliberately use/learn it again.

How would a native English speaker express the phrase "把英语捡起来"?

Comment: Most native speakers _would not have the faintest idea_ how to express something shown in Chinese writing.

Comment: Sorry, my Chinese isn't good enough. Do you mean start studying it again, or just practice in real life without taking formal instruction? Do they want to learn more, or practice what they know? Did they give up in despair or just reach a certain level and stop (do you want an expression "to try again after failure")? Regardless, things like "pick up", "take up again", "get back to", "take another shot at", etc, are OK.

Comment: @StuartF They abandoned using or learning English unconsciously for a long time and wanted to deliberately use/learn it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Resume" or "pick up" can be used.  It would help to include the word "study" somehow : pick up/resume my study of English/studying English.

Or there are endless paraphrases, "start doing something again", or "restart", or "have another go at doing something".